# Resize image with div binding

Tags: css

```html
<img src="https://picua.org/images/2019/09/09/a949c363f7cbb5eaa975aac572153236.png" style="position: absolute; width: 1700px;">
<div style="width: 50px; height: 50px; left: 170px; background: red; position: relative; top:150px;"></div>
```

Please tell me the formula. There is an image of 1700x1158 `div` has a position `left: 150px; top: 256px;` If the image has resized to 1099x749 how to calculate the position of the `div` so that it stays in the same place.

Comment: left += (∆width/2), top += (∆height / 2)

Comment: @David Can you please substitute my values?

Comment: Just use a calculator

Comment: ∆width means "original width - new width". Same principle with ∆height

Comment: @David What do you mean += and ∆

Comment: += means "add to current value"

Comment: @Will ((1700-1099)/2)+150 = 450.5 (left) right?

Comment: @Will Tell me please

Comment: The math is correct. Not sure if it produces what you're looking for though. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using image as background or within `<img>` tag.
If as background you can use `background-size: contain;` or `background-size: cover;`.
If that's not the answer you are looking for, please provide code or image for better understanding of a problem

Comment: you want div to be on top of image?